# Substring a middle characters in java

Tags: java, substring

I want to substring the value "o to p" in to two string variables like this

```
o
p
```

I tried to substring this code but it doesn't seems to work.

```
String x = rt.substring(rt.indexOf(" to ")+1);
```

this returns "to p"

Comment: Do you want first and last character?

Comment: i want to ignore " to " and save the rest into two variables. First and last character is not always a char it may be a string somewhat long

Comment: Use String.split method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] output = "o to p".split(" to ");
String var1 = output[0]; // "o"
String var2 = output[1]; // "p"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without `split` (which is easier, but anyway):

```
int pos = rt.indexOf(" to ");
String var1 = rt.substring(0, pos);
String var2 = rt.substring(pos + " to ".length());
```

The point you are missing is that `indexOf` returns the position of the  *start* of the search string; if you want what comes after it, you need to increase the index by the length of that search string.

Answer (score 0):

```
       String arr[] = rt.split("to");
        //arr[0] is the 1st part and arr[1] second.
```